# Oracle XE - Just can't login after install

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle10g, ora-01017

That sounds really stupid.

On Lubuntu 10.10, I did:

```
echo "deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update ; apt-get install oracle-xe
```

That brings me Oracle XE 10.2.0.1. And then:

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

Everything looks ok, including the password prompt and so. After that, I go to http://127.0.0.1:port/apex, and when I try to login with the username "SYSTEM", and the password I just typed. I get a "Invalid Login Credentials" error.

I also tried:

```
sqlplus /nolog
CONNECT
[ .. login and password .. ]
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Setting the environment variables also don't help.

```
sh oracle_env.sh
```

Well.. I just don't know what's happening. I repeated this procedure trying to find peculiar things, but always got the same results. Also tried some other users as "SYS". useless...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's amazing. The password can't be "admin". Please, let me know if anyone find this in the Oracle docs.

Comment: Whether you could connect as admin? `connect / as sysdba`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guys, I've been breakin my head with the same issue and finally got it logging in.. Here is the key.. http://www.linoob.com/2010/02/setting-up-oracle-xe-10g-in-ubuntu/
in case u ve already installed oracle, just remove it and purge and then reinstall with the steps in the given link..

And don't forget to give **a longer password** this time.. **"minimum 8 chars"** as I picked it up from some forum..

Comment: WTF LOLWUT?! If the password is min 8 chars, why won't the f**** installer tell me? This just cost me 2 hours of research...

Answer (score 3):

Exactly the same is happening to me in CentOS 5. With user SYSTEM or SYS, just after install and configure I cannot log in.

Comment: Is your password "admin"? That was my problem until now.

Comment: You solved it!There was a problem with my passwords file in linux. When installing oracle, I noticed this: Executing Post-install steps...
The /etc/passwords files was imutable. Just modified the permissions and worked.
id: cannot find name for group ID 800
usermod: unable to open password file
You must run '/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure' as the root user to
configure the database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make sure the pw is >= 8 characters in length.  It won't complain when setting on less than 8, but you won't be able to login !  With >= 8 in length, a successful login !!

Comment: Isn't the user supposed to login first to "INTERNAL" workspace? with "ADMIN" account? Never remember logging into APEX as SYSDBA

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Oracle is running before trying log in

`/etc/init.d/oracle-xe start` (Should be run as root).

Then in sql terminal try log in.

`connect / as sysdba`

Comment: The error ORA-01017 won't be thrown if the database is not running. Also, the $ORACLE_SID is properly set.